# English translation of "Onomasticon" by Julius Pollux of Naucratis?

Tags: translation, greek-language, julius-pollux, onomasticon-pollux

Is there an English translation of the *Onomasticon* by Julius Pollux of Naucratis?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it exists, but you might have a hard job finding a copy.

[WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/onomastikon-iouliou-poludeukou-the-onomasticon-of-julius-pollux-an-introduction-to-translation/oclc/37870057) has an entry with the following description:

> Onomastikon Iouliou Poludeukou = the Onomasticon of Julius Pollux : an introduction to translation
> Author:   Julius Pollux; Leland A Hall
> Publisher:    1960.
> Edition/Format:    Manuscript  Archival Material : English

With notes which seem to confirm that it's an English translation (in case you might think the "English" above is an archiver's error):

> "Prepared as an Honors Thesis for the Department of English, University of Oregon ... May 15, 1960."
> Typescript (carbon copy)--with handwritten corrections.
> Translation of various sections of the Onomastikon.
> "The translation has been made from the Lexicographi Graeci series, volumes IX and X, edited by Eric Bethe (Leipzig, 1932)."--Page iv.

Apparently, the manuscript is [available to borrow from University of Oregon libraries](https://alliance-primo.hosted.exlibrisgroup.com/primo-explore/search?tab=default_tab&search_scope=everything&vid=UO&fn=search&query=lsr02,contains,37870057).

I tried to find a Leland Hall who studied in the University of Oregon, and came across [this fellow](https://en-gb.facebook.com/leland.hall.4019):

> Studied at University of Oregon
> School year 1960

I don't have a Facebook account to see any more info about him, but it's possible he might respond to an interested reader about his work of sixty years ago.

---

The original [Greek text](https://scaife.perseus.org/reader/urn:cts:greekLit:tlg0542.tlg001.1st1K-grc1:2.157-2.158/), as well as a [Latin translation](https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb10314556_00001.html), are readily available online.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for an online interlinear Greek/English version as Oregon is a bit of a ride from Tucson, AZ., where I currently am!

Comment: According to https://www.worldcat.org/title/onomastikon-iouliou-poludeukou-the-onomasticon-of-julius-pollux-an-introduction-to-translation/oclc/37870057 this thesis has 53 leaves (= pages), while the work of Pollux comprises more than 120.000 Greek words!

Comment: It's described as "Translation of various sections" so it's clearly not complete.